# Both layers are in same CRS but in a different place

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers

I'm facing a problem with QGIS and have no clue what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried everything I know of.

I have polygon layer in CRS 2180. I add another layer that should be overlapping perfectly - and it does.

When I simply drag the layer to QGIS it fits perfectly fine, but when I change that new layer CRS to 2180 (THE SAME CRS THAT IM WORKING WITH) it goes somewhere far far away. I don't get it. Both layers are in the same CRS and they don't fit but when they're in different CRS then they fit. What am I doing wrong here?

I need them to be in the same CRS because otherwise the clip function doesn't work and I want to clip these new layers to only fit my original layer.

Comment: If you, instead of changing the CRS of the new layer, do _right click_ on it, _Export_, _Save Features As_, and assign the CRS _EPSG:2180_ in the _Save Vector Layer as_ dialog, the new layer created fits OK with the first one?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the Tour. This question is one of our more frequent recurring topics -- There is a difference between **changing** a coordinate reference and **projecting** to that reference. Changing CRS actually *corrupts* the target, which is why project-on-the-fly ceases to operate. You need to project the layer

Comment: Hi Adam - we don't have quite enough detail to be sure, but from what is in your question I think you've misunderstood the way that QGIS handles projections. To change the projection you don't change the setting in layer properties - you need to use 'save as' (as indicated in other answers including the one underdark links to). The projection setting in layer properties is designed to enable us to instruct QGIS as to what projection the data is *already* in (perhaps if QGIS has set this incorrectly).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are using wrong CRS when importing new layer. If you go to `Settings > Options > CRS`  you can set what CRS is used when importing layer:

[image]

If this setting does not import layer in desired CRS it means files already include information about CRS and you should use Gabriel De Luca´s suggestion to reproject it:  `Export > Save Features As`, secect desired CRS.